# UserInteractive Substring in text Label

Tags: ios, objective-c

i am generating a label in a view with label text retrieving from a JSON file.
now there are certain texts(values) retrieved from the JSON file that are user interactive texts (URL/some action) and some are not.
Now i am retrieving the data which are user interactive, setting them as text of a UILabel (which i created dynamically) and setting it in the view (PS. my view controller only has a 2 views inside,one that is default and another in which i am generating the label). 
The problem that is arising is that the interactive strings(labels) are set in one line and the ones that are not interactive are set in the next line(as i am creating individial labels for them) even if its a single word. 
I want to set the labels (with the texts - interactive/noninteractive) side by side untill there is no space.

Cant wrap my head around it because its a logical problem.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `NSAttributedString` is your friend when it comes to make rich/interactive labels... ;) > https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText *(or others...)*

Comment: i have already made interactive labels with texts coming from JSON, 
But among those texts there are certain non-interactive ones too. with separate keys, which i have retrieved and set label too.
the thing is the interactive ones and non-interactive ones dsnt comes in the same line,
always a new line is formed even for a single word